# RingoJS is not printing unicode characters

Tags: javascript, windows, unicode, cygwin, ringojs

I'm having trouble getting Ringo.JS to print unicode characters. My runtime environment is cygwin. I've boiled it down to a one-line program (see below) that exhibits the problem. The `cat` indicates my terminal is capable of displaying the unicode text, but ringo does not. I'm wondering if the "ringo" shell script is somehow being executed in a non-unicode conformant way, but I'm not fluent in the ways of `exec`-ing shells. much less in knowing why some methods may or may not have unicode support.

Is there a way to get ringo to print unicode correctly in cygwin?

```
$ cat unicodeTest.js
print( "αλφα" );
console.log( "αλφα" );
$ ringo unicodeTest.js
╬▒╬╗╧å╬▒
├Ä┬▒├Ä┬╗├ÅΓÇá├Ä┬▒
$ ringo --version
RingoJS version 0.10
$ which ringo
/cygdrive/c/bin/ringojs-0.10/bin/ringo
```

UPDATE:

Out of curiosity I tried redirecting the output to a file and checking it. There is definitely something wrong with the way ringo is running in my terminal, because the terminal can print unicode and ringo processes unicode correctly, but ringo won't print unicode in the terminal. Does anyone know what might cause this?

```
$ ringo unicodeTest.js  > output.text
├Ä┬▒├Ä┬╗├ÅΓÇá├Ä┬▒

$ cat output.text
αλφα
```

UPDATE #2:

It appears that ringo for windows is not built to support utf8 in console I/O. However, node.js works. I switched to a different machine running a different version of windows and got similar results.

```
$ cat utf8test.js
console.log( "καίρε, κόσμε" );
$ ringo utf8test.js
ÎºÎ±Î¹Ì�Ï�Îµ, ÎºÎ¿Ì�ÏƒÎ¼Îµ
$ node utf8test.js
καίρε, κόσμε
```

So bottom line, if you want to write a JavaScript program to do utf8 on the console in windows, then the solution is to use node.js and not ringojs. The node.js devs have added blocking I/O versions of a lot of the API (c.f. fs.readFile vs. fs.readFileSync), so you can pick the I/O model that suits your needs.

Comment: In general it’s safer to make your source code ASCII-only. If you need non-ASCII characters in string literals or regular expressions, [escape them](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%86%CE%B1), e.g. `'\u03B1\u03BB\u03C6\u03B1'`.

Comment: Ringo is assuming the console supports UTF-8 stream IO, which is common everywhere except Windows. Getting the Windows console to print Unicode from anything but a Win32-API-only app is astonishingly painful and generally better avoided.

Comment: @MathiasBynens While you are technically correct, escaped strings are not intelligible (I wouldn't know that `'\u03B1\u03BB\u03C6\u03B1'` is `αλφα` without a reference table). Code that isn't intelligible is not really maintainable, so escaping the strings doesn't really scale to an application.

Comment: @LeeJenkins You could use a transpiler that uses a library like [jsesc](http://mths.be/jsesc) to translate the string literals to their escaped form as part of a build step.